# Password protecting an upstream server using Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

I've been searching for ages and whilst I can find lots of questions about **proxying to** a password-protected server using Nginx, I can't find any references to how to go about **adding** basic authentication to an upstream server being proxied by Nginx.

I've currently got something like this:

```
location /private_area {
  auth_basic           "Private Area";
  auth_basic_user_file users.htpasswd;
  error_page           401 403 /how-to-request-access.html;
  proxy_pass           http://192.168.110.51:8100/backend_service;
  proxy_redirect       off;
  proxy_buffering      off;
  proxy_set_header     Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

but credentials are never requested.  (For clarity, I have simplified my setup a little: the location is actually a subdirectory of a similarly-proxied location, but one that doesn't require credentials and as such is a separate `location` block so presumably won't affect this block.)

Can `auth_basic` be used to password-protect a proxied server?  Am I going about it the right way?

---

**EDIT:** Addition of the output of `nginx -T`, slightly sanitised:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy-nginx:
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/html;

    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!

    server_tokens off;
    more_set_headers 'Server: ExampleServer';
    more_set_headers 'Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
    more_set_headers 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN';
    more_set_headers 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff';
    more_set_headers 'Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade';
    more_set_headers "Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(none), ambient-light-sensor=(none), autoplay=(none), battery=(none), camera=(none), display-capture=(none), document-domain=(none), gyroscope=(none), magnetometer=(none), midi=(none), payment=(none), microphone=(none), geolocation=(self), sync-xhr=(self)";
    #more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: default-src https: 'unsafe-inline'";
    #more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src data: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";
    more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: default-src data: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico {
    }

    location /nginx_status {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        stub_status;
    }

    location / {
        return 302 /portal/;
    }

    location /portal {
        proxy_pass      https://192.168.110.34;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /api {
        return 302 /api/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass      http://192.168.110.33/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /api/sub/ {
        proxy_pass      http://192.168.110.38:82/object/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /dashboard {
        return 302 /dashboard/;
    }

    location /dashboard/ {
        proxy_pass      http://192.168.110.32:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /service {
        return 302 /service/;
    }
    location = /service/ {
        return 302 /service/swagger-ui.html;
    }
    location /service/ {
        proxy_pass      http://192.168.110.51:8100/backend_service/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /service/private_area {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/service-access.log;
        auth_basic "Private Area";
        auth_basic_user_file service.htpasswd;
        error_page 401 403 /how-to-request-access.html;
        proxy_pass      http://192.168.110.51:8100/backend_service/private_area;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location = /how-to-request-access.html {
        internal;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question. Notice the capital `T`, it outputs the full server configuration.

Comment: Output uploaded earlier today, and I've since tried it again and it now seems to work!  Could it be something to do with caching from when I didn't have the basic auth in place??  I haven't changed anything since last week - essentially just restarted my browser!